# how compare two dates with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have three different types of dates and I can not compare them.

```
let withOneDayLess = moment().subtract(1, "days").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
//let justnow = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
let takenAt = moment.unix(story.takenAt).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

if(takenAt >= withOneDayLess){
    Arrstory.push(story)
     console.log(takenAt," - " ,withOneDayLess)
  };
```

`story.takenAt` is the date of a story in unix, and I need all the stories between yesterday and today, but I think the `if` compares only the first number, giving me stories that do not correspond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `currentDate` variable is also created as a `.format("DD-MM-YYYY")` method call... so you're not comparing dates - you're comparing strings.  Compare the dates to get your desired result:

```
var d1 = moment().subtract(1,"days");
var d2 = moment();
if (d1 < d2) alert(d1);


let currentDate = moment();
let story = { takenAt: 1746713004 };
let withOneDayLess = moment().subtract(1, "days").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
let justnow = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
let takenAt = moment.unix(story.takenAt).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

// this will never alert - typeof(takenAt) === "string" and the comparison
// "08-05-2025" is not >= "Sat Jan 05 2019 10:36:11 GMT-0800" as currentDate
// get coerced to a string to do the comparison if it's not a string already.
if(takenAt >= currentDate){
   alert("takenAt is later than currentDate");
}

// this WILL work because it's comparing a moment date to a moment date directly.
takenAt = moment.unix(story.takenAt);
if(takenAt >= currentDate){
   alert(takenAt.format("DD-MM-YYYY") + " is later than " + currentDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
}
```

Comment: nice, but takenAt is Unix and first i need convert the number in  human readable date

Comment: edited my answer to provide a more concise example -

Comment: Glad to help.  Can you flag my answer as correct and give me an upvote?  Thanks! :)